# How to generate a tree of categories showing there corresponding ratings from technical details table

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have two tables ecategory(id, name, parent_id) and technical_detail(id, tech_interview_id, category_id)

technical_details has category_id as foreign key for ecategory table.

How to generate a tree(parent-child) of categories showing there corresponding ratings from technical details table using cakePHP 3.

[image: Ecategory]

[image: technical_details]

```
$this->Ecategory->recursive = 2;
$cond['conditions']     = array('Ecategory.parent_id' => 0);
$ecategories = $this->Ecategory->find('all', $cond);

foreach ($ecategories as $k => $row) {
    $cat_ids[] = $row['Ecategory']['id'];
}

$cond['conditions']     = array('Technicaldetail.category_id in' => $cat_ids);
$technicalDetails       = $this->Technicaldetail->find('all', $cond);
```

Comment: you should show your efforts so far, and your desired output. Also, did you attach the tree behavior to  CategoriesTable?

Comment: Yess, Please find the code now. Some categories will not have there ratings so it will be counted as zero rating

Comment: Sure it is cake3?

Comment: Oops its 2.3.1 tagged the wrong version